# What is an efficient way to find the first occurrence of an element after a given position in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

For example,
Consider the array

```
A = [1,2,3,1,1,2,1,4,5,6,1,2,3]
```

The first occurrence (index of the occurrence) of the element `1` after index `2` in the array is `3`

The first occurrence of the element `2` after the index `2` in the array is `5`

The first occurrence of the element `1` after the index `4` in the array is `6`

If there is no occurrence after a particular, index, we can just output `-1`

How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: How would you do it efficiently if you didn't have that "after a given position" requirement?

Comment: Then I would just put them into a `HashTable` when I first saw them.

Comment: So it's a big array. Because to do it *efficiently* for an array that size, I would just do a loop.

Comment: Dictionary of numbers -> list of positions, use binary search to find the closest position after finding the number in the dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a one-time query, you can't do better than linear searching the array after that position : O(n).

If you need to execute similar queries on the same array multiple times, build a hash multimap from each distinct element to a sorted list of the indices in which it occurs. Then it's just a question of a) looking up the sorted list for the element b) binary searching the sorted list (the match doesn't need to be exact), and then returning the successor element / first element larger than the specified position. I'm sure you can handle cases when `-1` should be returned. This is O(1) + O(logn) = O(logn).

Comment: I don't get the O(1) part. Should not it take O(nlgn) time to build the hashed map?

Comment: @Fallen: The one-time cost of building up the data-structure is not included in that - only the querying cost which is: a constant time hash lookup + a logarithmic time binary search.

Comment: Presumably building the hashmap would be a one-time occurrence, whereas the lookup would be done a lot.

Comment: It will take just `O(n)` time to build the HashMap. You need to go through the list only once. For every element, if it is already present in the map, append it to the list associated with the element. Else add a new entry.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea of O(mlogn) if the numbers are integers. Here m is the number of query.

First we need to store a vector < int>[100]. It stores the accurance of the number.
For each query . binary search the vector  (here vector is in increasing order), and it takes in O(logn). Hence it is O(mlogn).

if the number in the array is float number, we should change vector< int >[100] to  map < float, vector >, then it takes O(m*logn*logn).